# matplotlib animated line plot stays empty

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to follow the basic animation tutorial located [here](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) and adapting it to display an already computed dataset instead of evaluating a function every frame, but am getting stuck. My dataset involves XY coordinates over time, contained in the lists `satxpos` and `satypos` I am trying to create an animation such that it traces a line starting at the beginning of the dataset through the end, displaying say 1 new point every 0.1 seconds. Any help with where I'm going wrong?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np

Code here creates satxpos and satypos as lists

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-1e7,1e7), ylim = (-1e7,1e7))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(satxpos[i], satypos[i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames = len(satxpos), interval = 1, blit=True)
```

Edit: The code runs without errors, but generates a blank plot window with no points/lines displayed and nothing animates. The dataset is generated correctly and views fine in a static plot.

Comment: Is this all of your code? Are you getting any error messages when you run it?

Comment: It is not all the code, the parts that generate satxpos and satypos do create valid datasets. I can view those as a static plot just fine. Code runs without errors, but the plot thats generated is just a blank window, no animation or points/lines are displayed

Comment: Do you use `anim.save()` and `plt.show()` at some point in the code you didn't share?

Comment: I actually didn't have `plt.show()`, however the plot window came up anyway. I tried adding it, and no difference.running the example code exhibits the same behavior, but the example code animates.  I did not use `anim.save` as I am not interested in writing the animation to a file for now, just viewing it.

Comment: And the elements in `satxpos` and `satypos` are `np` `numpy` objects?

Comment: Yes satxpos and satypos are arrays, as that is what np.linspace creates

Comment: `satxpos` and `satxpos` cannot be just `np.linspace`. It won't work. It has to be a 2-D array where each row is one `np.linspace`. I provided a valid example of `satxpos` and `satxpos` and some trouble shooting ideas in my answer.

Comment: I bet if you use `line, =ax.plot([], [], 'o')` you will see a single point moving around

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to "trace a line starting at the beginning of the dataset through the end" you would index your arrays to contain one more element per timestep:

```
line.set_data(satxpos[:i], satypos[:i])
```

(Note the `:`!)

Everything else in the code looks fine, such that with the above manipulation you should get and extending line plot. You might then want to set `interval` to something greater than 1, as that would mean 1 millesecond timesteps (which might be a bit too fast). I guess using `interval = 40` might be a good start.

Comment: That solved it, works exactly as I intended now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct! So long as satxpos and satypos are both configured and initialized properly, I believe everything else is valid!

One part of the code you do not show in your question is the invocation of the `anim.save()` and `plt.show()` functions, which are both necessary for your code to work (as per the tutorial you shared!)

You would therefore need to add something like:

```
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])

plt.show()
```

to the end of your code to create the animation (and show it, I presume)!

Hope it helps!

[Source - Matplotlib Animation Tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

I saw you mentioned "the parts that generate satxpos and satypos do create valid datasets. I can view those as a static plot just fine". But my guess is still the problem originated from your `satxpos` and `satypos`.

One way you can trouble shoot is to replace your two functions and animation code with `line.set_data(satxpos[i], satypos[i])`. Set `i` as `0`, `1`, ... and see if you can see the plot. If not, your `satxpos` and `satypos` are not as valid as you claimed.

As an example, a valid `satxpos` and `satypos` can be like this:

```
x = np.array([np.linspace(-1e7, 1e7, 1000)])
i = 200
satxpos = x.repeat(i, axis=0)
satypos = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (satxpos - 0.01 * np.arange(i).reshape(-1, 1).repeat(satxpos.shape[1], axis=1)))
satypos *= 1e7 / 2
```

This works with the code you provided thus indicating the code you've shown us is fine.

## Edit in response to comments:

If your `satxpos` and `satypos` are just `np.linespace`, the animation loop will get just one point with `(satxpos[i], satypos[i])` and you won't see the point on the plot without a setting like `marker='o'`. Therefore, you see nothing in your animation.