# Animating a line plot over time

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, visualization

Time series data is data over time. I am trying to animate a line plot of time series data in python. In my code below this translates to plotting `xtraj` as they and `trange` as the x. The plot does not seem to be working though.

I have found similar questions on Stack overflow but none of the solutions provided here seem to work. Some similar questions are [matplotlib animated line plot stays empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155014/matplotlib-animated-line-plot-stays-empty), [Matplotlib FuncAnimation not animating line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875827/matplotlib-funcanimation-not-animating-line-plot) and a tutorial referencing the help file [Animations with Matplotlib](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ek3Fbr5CN8dvKwYyC8FkN_gPIB-2TtV-#scrollTo=SgTiVfjlrrmG).

I begin by creating the data with the first part and simulating it with the second. I tried renaming the data that would be used as y-values and x-values in order to make it easier to read.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


dt = 0.01
tfinal = 5.0
x0 = 0


sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
n = int(tfinal/dt)
xtraj = np.zeros(n+1, float)
trange = np.linspace(start=0,stop=tfinal ,num=n+1) 
xtraj[0] = x0

for i in range(n):
    xtraj[i+1] = xtraj[i] + np.random.normal() 

x = trange
y = xtraj

# animation line plot example

fig = plt.figure(4)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5, 5), ylim=(0, 5))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(x)+1,interval=200, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am new to working in Python and particularly trying to animate plots. So I  must apologize if this question is trivial.

### Summary

So to summarize my question how does one animate time series in Python, iterating over the time steps (x-values).

Comment: First off, please use `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. Importing pyplot as `py` is extremely confusing. Possibly in your environment you need to add `plt.show()` at the end so the animation gets triggered.  Also, it would be helpful to set the some fixed x and y limits at the start to enclose the entire plot, e.g. `ax.set_xlim(trange[0], trange[-1]); ax.set_ylim(xtraj.min()-1, xtraj.max()+1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

dt = 0.01
tfinal = 1
x0 = 0

sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
n = int(tfinal/dt)
xtraj = np.zeros(n+1, float)
trange = np.linspace(start=0,stop=tfinal ,num=n+1)
xtraj[0] = x0

for i in range(n):
    xtraj[i+1] = xtraj[i] + np.random.normal()

x = trange
y = xtraj

# animation line plot example

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (6, 6))

def animate(i):
    ax.cla() # clear the previous image
    ax.plot(x[:i], y[:i]) # plot the line
    ax.set_xlim([x0, tfinal]) # fix the x axis
    ax.set_ylim([1.1*np.min(y), 1.1*np.max(y)]) # fix the y axis

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(x) + 1, interval = 1, blit = False)
plt.show()
```

The code above reproduces this animation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Andrea Blengino. This helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much :-)

Comment: Its a pleasure Andrea , could I ask a good recommendation on learning about animation in matplotlib, other than the documentation would you recommend something you've used before.

Comment: @Konqui: Even this results in an empty plot on my screen. Any reason why that might be?

Comment: Did you copied exactly the above code? If so and still you get an empty plot, try to ask a new question with your issue

Comment: How do you make it work in colab? or to save the video with correct time intervals?