# Matplotlib animate showing up empty plot even while using a basic tutorials

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, matplotlib-animation

I used the exact code from [this StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335385/animating-a-line-plot-over-time-in-python)

When I run this code, this is all I see:

I wish I had more details to provide but I'm confused as to why even this simple example is not showing up correctly.

[image]

Comment: are you using a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @ombk - Yes I am

Comment: `%matplotlib notebook`
 add this to ur code  thank me later

Comment: @ombk That did the trick

Comment: happy it worked ^_^

Answer (score 0):

As I see you use Jupyter Notebook, so you should run this command to to show up `matplotlib` results:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

also you need there to use `HTML` from `IPython.display`. Then pass your animation converted to html video to this `HTML` function:

```
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

There is a full example below. I'm using [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335385/animating-a-line-plot-over-time-in-python) you cited in your question and changed it little bit:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML


dt = 0.01
tfinal = 5.0
x0 = 0


sqrtdt = np.sqrt(dt)
n = int(tfinal/dt)
xtraj = np.zeros(n+1, float)
trange = np.linspace(start=0,stop=tfinal ,num=n+1) 
xtraj[0] = x0

for i in range(n):
    xtraj[i+1] = xtraj[i] + np.random.normal() 

x = trange
y = xtraj

# animation line plot example

fig = plt.figure(4)
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-5, 5), ylim=(0, 5))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(x)+1,interval=200, blit=False)


HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```